# PHP pass variable from while loop to Select query on another page

Tags: php, mysql

I have page named `prototype.php`  and there is a while loop where I echo buttons. And when you click that button you are redirected to `"proto.php?id=".$row['id']` And on that page a table needs to be shown with the content that contains the rows that have the id of the button. But I don't know how to pass the variable from `prototype.php` to `"proto.php?id=".$row['id']`

This is my while loop:

```
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM theme";
    $result = $con->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $your_url= "proto.php?id=".$row['id'];
            echo '<a href="'.$your_url.'"><input type="button" value="'. $row["theme_name"].'"></a>';

        }
    } else {
        echo "no results";
    }
?>
```

And this is `"proto.php?id=".$row['id']`:

```
$row = $_GET['id'];
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Norm LEFT JOIN Org ON norm.org_id = org.id  LEFT JOIN Cluster ON norm.cluster_id = cluster.id LEFT JOIN Orden ON norm.orden_id = orden.id LEFT JOIN Users ON norm.user_id = users.id WHERE theme_id = $_GET['id']";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo"<th>Norm Org</th>";
            echo "<th>Norm id</th>";
            echo "<th>Norm</th>";
            echo "<th>Ordenen</th>";
            echo "<th>Clusteren</th>";
            echo "<th>Verantwoordelijke</th>";
            echo "</tr>";

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                if ($row['orden_name']) {
                    $data_list = $row['orden_name'];
                } else {
                  $data_list = $dropdown_list;
                }
                 if ($row['cluster_name']) {
                    $data_list2 = $row['cluster_name'];
                } else {
                  $data_list2 = $dropdown_list2;
                }
                 if ($row['user_name']) {
                    $data_list3 = $row['user_name'];
                } else {
                  $data_list3 = $dropdown_list3;
                }
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['org_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='row_count'>" . $row['norm_id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['norm_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $data_list . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $data_list2 . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $data_list3 . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

            }
            echo "</table>";
            // Free result set
            mysqli_free_result($result); 
          }else{
            echo "No records were found.";
        }

    } else {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: First of all, stop nesting `input` in `a`, that is invalid HTML. And secondly - what _exactly_ is the problem now here? Not sure what you are even asking.

Comment: Take a look at the manual, specifically the `$_GET` array

Comment: Do you mean you want to read url parameter and don't know how?

Comment: How do i make sure that the table in is only selecting the rows that contain the id from `$your_url= "proto.php?id=".$row['id'];`

Comment: Try using sessions, i had a similar problem got it working by using sessions

Comment: use `$_GET['id']`

Comment: Where do i put the `$_GET['id']`

Comment: put it in proto.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in **proto.php** this line: `WHERE theme_id = '1'";`

to this: `WHERE theme_id = " . $_GET['id'] . ";";`